# Could cilliates evolve into multicellular creatures?

Tags: biology, evolution

Would it be possible for a cilliate, such as *Stentor*, to evolve into a large multicellular organism similar in form to the original unicellular body-plan?

Answer (score 4):

**Volvox style?**

[image: volvox]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvox

The constituent organism of a volvox colony are not ciliates, but photosynthetic algae with flagellae.  Their photosynthetic lifestyle lends itself to scaling up; more surface areas and predators the size of the individual component cells cannot fit the colony in its mouth.

Ciliates are non-photosynthetic which makes it trickier, but I can imagine a similar scaleup for those that feed with a sort of ram-scoop mouth.  Volvox have just 2 cell types - the reproducers in the middle and the workers on the outside but a colonial ciliate with the same body plan would probably need both of those and a third type dedicated to enclosing food items in enormous 1-cell vacuoles.

Comment: But what about the cilliate splitting into multiple cells in the cilliate's original form?

Comment: You want a facultative multicellular creature?  Something like a slime mold where they can operate as individuals or a commune?

Comment: No, I mean were the cilliate goes from, for example, a unicellular cone-shaped creature directly to a multicellular cone-shaped creature

Comment: There are colonial ciliates; hydrotheca for one. I think stentor have also been observed clustering. But as you say, you would need specialists in the colony before making the jump to true multicellularity.